# How to retrieve an array of values from Java API in Karate?

Tags: automation, frameworks, soapui, karate

I'm reading WSDL path and XML Request from excel file. I need to use these two data in my feature file. Reading action has been done on Java side but I don't know how to pass these into Karate - feature file.

I'm aware of single value passing from Java API to Karate like this.

```
   * xmlstring xmlVar = response
   * def APIHelperClass = Java.type('com.org.utilities.APIHelperClass')
   * def result = APIHelperClass.getResponseFromFeatureFile(xmlVar,'getMembersDetailsResponse.xml')
```

Suggest me how to receive multiple values / array from JavaAPI into Karate.

Thanks

Comment: Accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this example: [`cats-java.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/java/cats-java.feature) and the corresponding Java class: [`JavaDemo.java`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/demo/util/JavaDemo.java).

So if you return data as a Java `List` it will be a JSON array. And a `Map` becomes a JSON object. This is explained [in the documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java).

In your case if you return a `HashMap` with 2 keys e.g. `wsdlPath` and `xmlRequest` you should be easily able to use it in Karate.